# How to set the screen height and width by %(percentage) in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am using one plugin for slider. That slider contains H & W is mentioned by pixel. I want that in %

```
$("#section4").awShowcase(
    {
        content_width:          1000,
        content_height:         300,
}
});
```

They are mentioned by like this. how to change this by % - Percentage.

I want that for responsive model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
$("#section4").awShowcase({
    content_width: '50%',
    content_height: '50%',
//}  // Remove this
});
```

Also, you're having redundant `}` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#section4").awShowcase(
    {
        content_width:          100%,
        content_height:         30%,
  }
});
```

Is this what you looking for?